# How to fix Invalid parameter number in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I got the "Invalid parameter number" when I use PDO

I try to see if parameters are OK, and they are

There's my code:

```php
        //==== Méthode permettant d'obtenir le mdp de l'utilisateur
        public function getPassword($nom){
            try {
                $sql = "SELECT
                            `password`
                        FROM
                            personne
                        WHERE
                            `nom_personne` = :nom OR `nom_personne` = lcase(:nom)";

                $req = $this->bd->prepare($sql);
                $req->bindValue(':nom',strtoupper($nom));
                $req->execute();
                $tab = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
                if ($tab !== "")
                    return $tab;
                else
                    return false;

            } catch (PDOException $e){
                die('<p> Erreur : '. $e->getMessage().'</p>');
            }
        }
```

It should return the password for a user, but it return the error. Can someone help me please ?

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#emulation_on

Comment: Note you don't have to test both uppercase and lower case if you use a case-insensitive collation. The default collation in MySQL is case-insensitive. So if you haven't changed that, you shouldn't need two terms in your WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is more simple:

```
$sql = "SELECT
                            `password`
                        FROM
                            personne
                        WHERE
                            `nom_personne` = :nom";

$req = $this->bd->prepare($sql);
$req->execute(['nom' => $nom]);
return $req->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: I took a liberty to make it even simpler :)

Comment: I found the solution, wich was
```php
$sql = "SELECT `password`
                  FROM personne
                  WHERE UCASE(`nom_personne`) = UCASE(:nom)";
           
          $req = $this->bd->prepare($sql);
          $req->bindValue( ':nom', $nom );
          $req->execute();
          $tab = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
          if ($tab !== "")
              return $tab;
          else
              return false;
```